# Cannot fix CSS for IE - Help?

Tags: css, html

In FF the site below works as expected but in IE the Search and Basket that are on the right in FF are put to the left, beneath the Products and Categories.

Problem Site - http://ci2.totalshopuk.com/

I want to move away from the Tables at http://www.totalshopuk.com so any help with the DIV conversion would be a great help!

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1px border-right on your wrapper class, makes your total pixels greater then the 960px width of container, so it wraps to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `float: left;` on `.wrapper`.